# Extract the IP address and port number from a environment variable using windows batch command

Tags: linux, windows, parsing, batch-file

I have an `environment variable` in windows which has a `value` as follows

```
"https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/xxxx        (login: xxx, password: xxxxx)"
```

My task is to `extract the IP address and port number` from the *environment variable*. I was able to do this in a Linux environment. The commands are as follows

```
echo "$env_variable" | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d ':' -f 1 - for the IP Address
echo "$env_variable" | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d ':' -f 2 - for the port number
```

Can somebody help me to do same using the `windows batch command` on windows system?

**EDIT**

Here `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the IP Address and `yyyy` is the port number.

Comment: I'd rather put the data in a better format, e.g. multiple variables, they are after all meant for easy machine consumption, not pretty printed info for the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set var="https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/xxxx        (login: xxx, password: xxxxx)"
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=/:" %%a in (%var%) do (
   set ip=%%a
   set port=%%b
)
echo %ip%, %port%
```